# How to add math symbols to contour label

Tags: r, visualization, contour

I can't seem to pass math symbols to a contour label. Is this possible?

Example:

```
image(volcano)
contour(volcano, level=150, add=TRUE, label = "150") # works
contour(volcano, level=120, add=TRUE, label = expression(alpha)) # doesn't work
contour(volcano, level=110, add=TRUE, label = bquote(alpha)) # doesn't work
text(0.5,0.5, labels = bquote(alpha == .(120))) # works
text(0.2,0.5, labels = expression(paste(alpha, "= 150"))) # works
```

[image]

Comment: not sure, but have your tried out using unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
image(volcano);
levels <- c(150, 120, 110);
for (i in 1:length(levels)) {
    contour(
        volcano, add = TRUE,
        level = levels[i], 
        label = sprintf("a = %i", levels[i]), 
        vfont = c("sans serif symbol", "plain"), labcex = 1);
}
```

[image]

The key here is to use `vfont` to force Hershey vector fonts instead of the current font family. You can then use the "HersheySansSymbol" font family to typeset "a" as "α", by using the `contour` function argument `vfont = c("sans serif symbol", "plain")`. It's a bit hidden, but more details on the Hershey fonts can be found in `?Hershey`.

PS. You can also use a seriffed bold font with `vfont = c("serif symbol", "bold")`.

Comment: Excellent - that was indeed hidden. Slightly more straightforward are the direct calls to Greek symbols (outlined in `demo(Hershey)`): `contour(volcano, level=120, add=TRUE, label = paste0("\\*a=", 120), labcex=1)`